# Passing paramarray into function requiring paramarray

Tags: excel, vba

In excel-vba, how do I pass a paramarray into a function which expects the same paramarray? I've been looking around but can't seem to find any answers to this specific problem

My code looks like this:

```
Sub test()
    GetRefData "SPX Index", "PX_LAST", "PX_VOLUME", "PE_RATIO", "PX_TO_CASH_FLOW"
End Sub

Public Function GetRefData(security As String, ParamArray fields() As Variant) As String
    Debug.Print fields(0) // returns "PX_LAST"
    SendReq security, fields
End Function

Sub SendReq(security, ParamArray fields() As Variant)
    Debug.Print fields(0) // returns type mismatch
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm not sure what your problem is. If I remove the brackets around the call to GetRefData in Sub test, then I can put a breakpoint in SendReq and the fields parameter has 4 items with the expected string values.

Comment: Hi DeanOC, thank you for your reply.  Are you saying that the code works when you run it? For example, if I use `Debug.Print fields(0)` when I am in SendReq, VBA returns a 'type mismatch' error

Comment: See "Passing a ParamArray variable to another procedure" here: http://www.tushar-mehta.com/publish_train/xl_vba_cases/1005%20ParamArray.shtml

Comment: Thanks Tim Williams!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking up [the article Tim posted](http://www.tushar-mehta.com/publish_train/xl_vba_cases/1005%20ParamArray.shtml), the solution was that paramarrays have to be accessed one level deeper when passed as a parameter, ie:

```
Sub SendReq(security, ParamArray fields() As Variant)
    Debug.Print fields(0)(0)
End Sub
```

Comment: Yep! The second fields(0) **(0)** parameter did the trick